# Accessing a Windows COM Interface using Java, Error loading type library/DLL. : .\com4j.cpp

Tags: java, windows, interface, com

I need to access a Windows COM interface using my Java application. The COM interface in inbuilt in the executable for the program I'm talking to.

I tried com4j but keep getting this exception, I'm running it only from the command prompt for now-

```
cmd:> java -jar tlbimp.jar -o exe -p abc.exe executableFile.exe

Exception in thread "main" com4j.ExecutionException: com4j.ComException: 80029c4
a LoadTypeLib failed : Error loading type library/DLL. : .\com4j.cpp:398
        at com4j.ComThread.execute(ComThread.java:203)
        at com4j.Task.execute(Task.java:25)
        at com4j.COM4J.loadTypeLibrary(COM4J.java:322)
        at com4j.tlbimp.driver.Lib.getLibid(Lib.java:90)
        at com4j.tlbimp.driver.Driver.addLib(Driver.java:38)
        at com4j.tlbimp.driver.Main.doMain(Main.java:123)
        at com4j.tlbimp.driver.Main.main(Main.java:56)
Caused by: com4j.ComException: 80029c4a LoadTypeLib failed : Error loading type
library/DLL. : .\com4j.cpp:398
        at com4j.Native.loadTypeLibrary(Native Method)
        at com4j.COM4J$2.call(COM4J.java:324)
        at com4j.COM4J$2.call(COM4J.java:322)
        at com4j.Task.invoke(Task.java:51)
        at com4j.ComThread.run0(ComThread.java:153)
        at com4j.ComThread.run(ComThread.java:134)
```

What (if any) are the workarounds? Is this the correct approach to begin with? Never worked with COM before, so I'm wondering if I'm on the right path here.

Also if this command were to work, I believe I would get Java definitions for all the interfaces in there, which I can then access directly in my code?

Do I have to run this command from my java code every time my program starts up and generate new objects or is this a one time thing?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. try to `regsvr32 executableFile.exe` 2. how do you creating com object?

Comment: 1. Returned an error as well, says make sure its a valid dll or ocx file. Does that mean there is some problem with the executable itself? Its a third party thing, so I probably would have to ask them to install it again.

Comment: looks like problem with .exe, just info for you: com objects can be stored either in exe or dll files, if you want to use them - they should be installed, this is done by regsvr32 utility, if com object is installed - then you can create them from code, also you can check whether this file is valid at all - try to download depends.exe utility from microsoft site and open exe via it

Comment: Okay, thanks, let me look into and get back

Comment: The executable problem was fixed, I was able to generate the required objects and access the interface using those. Thanks for your help!